# Unable to invoke "btoa" and "item.slice" method in my script for retrieving the playlist

Tags: javascript, next.js, next-auth

Whenever I am trying to invoke the "btoa" method, I am not able to use this within my script. I created a variable to store the `client id: client_secret` in base64. The id and secrets are being retrieved from the ".env" file.
I have also tried to use the `Buffer` method, but unable to use this as well. I am getting the error "invalid from" in `Buffer`.

can someone help me?

Please look at the full code,

```js
const client_id = process.env.SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID;
const client_secret = process.env.SPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET;
const refresh_token = process.env.SPOTIFY_REFRESH_TOKEN;

const basic = btoa(`${client_id}:${client_secret}`);
const NOW_PLAYING_ENDPOINT = `https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/currently-playing`;
const TOP_TRACKS_ENDPOINT = `https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/top/tracks`;
const TOKEN_ENDPOINT = `https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token`;

const getAccessToken = async () => {
  const response = await fetch(TOKEN_ENDPOINT, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Basic ${basic}`,
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    body: new URLSearchParams({
      grant_type: 'refresh_token',
      refresh_token
    })
  });

  return response.json();
};

export const getNowPlaying = async () => {
  const { access_token } = await getAccessToken();

  return fetch(NOW_PLAYING_ENDPOINT, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}`
    }
  });
};

export const getTopTracks = async () => {
  const { access_token } = await getAccessToken();

  return fetch(TOP_TRACKS_ENDPOINT, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}`
    }
  });
};
```

Using the above script I am trying to embed the customized Spotify play on my site. This wrapper is intended to display the top track as well.

Also, whenever I am trying to run the wrapper used to display the top tracks, it displays the following error,

[image]

Full code for displaying the top tracks:

```js
import { type NextRequest } from 'next/server';
import { getTopTracks } from 'lib/spotify';

export const config = {
  runtime: 'experimental-edge'
};

export default async function handler(req: NextRequest) {
  const response = await getTopTracks();
  const { items } = await response.json();

  const tracks = items.slice(0, 10).map((track) => ({
    artist: track.artists.map((_artist) => _artist.name).join(', '),
    songUrl: track.external_urls.spotify,
    title: track.name
  }));

  return new Response(JSON.stringify({ tracks }), {
    status: 200,
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      'cache-control': 'public, s-maxage=86400, stale-while-revalidate=43200'
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: PLEASE be careful with your spelling.  The API is `btoa`, not `btao`.  The name stands for "bytes to ASCII".  And you haven't told us what actually DOES happen when you use this.  Did you print the value of `basic` to see what you get?  And who do you think is substituting those `${...}` strings?

Comment: Yeah, please include the line of code you try to run followed by a comment detailing the error logged. Do this for both variants (btoa and Buffer.from(str).toString('base64')

Comment: Thanks @TimRoberts I have updated the question title. But still I am using the same API and it is getting struck.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you misspelled the Bytes to ASCII function, it is `btoa`, not `btao`.

If you are looking to do it the other way around, spell it `atob`.

Comment: No, he did not.  He misspelled it in the title, but not in the code.